# JavaScript RegEx match wrong when backslash in tested string

Tags: javascript, regex, backslash

I'm trying to match and highlight any string from a source file with regex

```
/(["'])([^\1]+?)(?:\1)/g
```

Mostly it does fine, but when the tested string has ie.

> `cout << this->name << "(" << this->x << "," << this->y << ") r=" << this->distance() << "\n";`

it breaks and highlights `(`, `,` and `<< this->distance() <<` and not `(`, `,` and `\n` like it should.

I've now concluded that it's the backslash (escape character) breaks the highlighting since replacing `\n` with `endl` again produces the wanted outcome.

Why is this and how can I make the highlighting work and wanted?

Comment: You seem to think that `[^\1]` will create a negated character class (from either `'` or `"`). But it doesn't - both `\\` and `1` are treated literally when within the brackets.

Comment: I did but I'm not anymore. Have to study the negative lookahead more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match the following characters(characters which are just after to `"` or `'`) using a negative lookahead.

```
(["'])(?:\\.|(?!\1).)*\1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yA6hF9/1)

Comment: +1, nice approach (although it will break at escaped quotation marks).

Comment: No, that's not going to work. This - `(["'])(?:\\.|(?!\1).)*\1` - however, is. ) [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yA6hF9/1).

Comment: Because it's not a valid code. ) The point is, any string literal might have `\"` or `\'` sequences within (check the first one in the demo).

Comment: @raina77ow `(?<!\\)(["'])(?:(?!\1).)*\1` won't match the escaped `'` or double quotes.  I don't know , what's wrong with this..

Comment: @user3187600 may i now the reason for unaccepting this answer?

Comment: Please apply your regex to the code in my demo ([here](http://regex101.com/r/zC9xK6/1)); see how the very first escaped `"` symbol is treated as the end of the string literal. You're guarding against the non-existant cases, but miss the ones that do exist. It should at least be written [like this](http://regex101.com/r/oW0wF7/1).

Comment: javascript hasn't negative lookbehind as such and I don't know how to substitute it.

Comment: @user3187600 i didn't use a negative lookbehind. this http://regex101.com/r/oW0wF7/2 would compensate that.

Comment: `((?!\\).)` => `[^\\]`

Comment: @raina77ow i forget the start `(^|(?!\\).)((["'])(?:\\.|(?!\3).)*\3)` or `(^|[^\\])((["'])(?:\\.|(?!\3).)*\3)`

Comment: The regex: `/(["'])(?:\\.|(?!\1).)*\1/` experiences catastrophic backtracking when applied to a non-matching string having lots of escapes, e.g. `abc"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\def`. The problem is that the two group alternatives are not mutually exclusive (both match an escape). Easily fixed by changing the dot to: `[^\\]`. Otherwise, this is a pretty clever solution.